# Does the order of header properties matter?

Tags: php, html, properties, meta

**Does the order of header properties matter in HTML and PHP?**

In PHP, you can specify headers for a file like this:

`header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8")`. Can the order of `Content-type` and `charset` be swapped? Can `Content-type` have no capital `C`?

Another example might be `initial-scale` and `width` in HTML viewport meta tags. Can the order be swapped?

What will work and what won't? Why? Are these properties case sensitive? Can they be reordered?

EDIT: People are asking what reordered means in this case, for example....

Can `Content-type` and `charset` go the other way round in a `header()` function like `header("charset: UTF-8; Content-type: text/css")`

EDIT: It turns out that the PHP header tag does not work if you reorder the properties, but they are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reorder on PHP header tags, but you can on meta tags.

They are not case sensitive.

Comment: Can `Content-type` and `charset` go the other way round in a `header()` function like `header("charset: UTF-8; Content-type: text/css")`

Comment: oooh, my bad, i just read it wrong, i thought you were asking if they can be reCorded. Apoligies. Yes to answer your question

Comment: So can I or can I not reorder them?

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Actually you are wrong about the ordering in PHP header functions, they have to stay in the same order

Comment: But they are not case sensitive

Comment: I am waiting for an edit on this answer to be approved by the moderators.

Comment: Nope, pretty sure they don't work in css docs, tried everything.

Comment: I just marked your answer as correct after I edited it